# Why do some systemctl operations output to stderr?

Tags: command-line, bash, systemd

I've created a service; lets call it `abc.service`. I run:

```
sudo systemctl enable /home/pi/abc.service 1>output.txt 2>error.txt
```

and `output.txt` is empty while `error.txt` contains:

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/abc.service -> /home/pi/abc.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/abc.service -> /home/pi/abc.service.
```

Why is this?

EDIT: My purpose is this -- I have a global program running that can run commands, and commands with stderr are flagged and printed to error files. However, it seems like systemd is printing to stderr (and therefore my error files) even though it seems like it's not an error.

EDIT2: Example systemd file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test file

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/ls /home/pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Just tested, enabling this file prints to stderr (like `error.txt` from above). Tested service, prints dir contents of home directory.

Comment: adding your abc.service content might help too.

Comment: @dedunumax done.

Comment: Not an expert but are you running `ls` at a time there is no standard output to display on? If so output to Standard Error sounds benefitial.

Comment: I've run/restarted this script during appropriate times where displays were available and the system was fully booted to a desktop @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: did you find the solution for your problem? I also have this and would like to not have this as en error....

Comment: @oberfreak I have not. Granted -- I have not been looking into it; it is not a _huge_ problem for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of documentation here:
[systemd man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)

You might also redirect the "enable" output to stdout (although that might redirect real errors there too.

It does seem like the action does not follow Unix "standards" as to what is an error and what is not.

Comment: I've looked into bypassing my own error/warning filters for certain text, like the one outputted by `enable`, but it seems like the wrong solution and may be tedious to deal with in the future if and when that text ever changes (likely? probably not...)