# Disable output of systemctl and apt-get

Tags: apt, server, 20.04, output

I'm currently writing a script that installs and configures the Samba server automatically for me. I was wondering why this command `sudo apt-get -y install samba > /dev/null && sudo systemctl enable smbd.service > /dev/null` still gives this output.

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Synchronizing state of smbd.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable smbd
```

How can I prevent the commands from giving any output?

Thanks

Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: This is outside the scope of the question, but why would you *not* want to see the output of software being installed? This is a very simple way to see if there are problems before they become problems. Is the goal to have this script run on a fleet of systems to quietly start up Samba shares?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Does [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1182696/26246) the question? seems related to stderr stream.

Comment: @matigo No, I'm just planning to install Samba on a single local nas machine, but the parts haven't arrived yet and I wanted to learn a bit more about bash scripting because I was bored. And to why I don't want to see the output: To be honest, I don't know...

Comment: @user.dz Not sure where this config file is or what command I'd need. But this would probably help me.

Comment: @driver1848 try this `sudo apt-get -yy install samba 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null && sudo systemctl enable smbd.service 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null` (it redirects stderr too).

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue!

Answer (score 6):

`>` will redirect only `stdout`. `stderr` stream should be redirected too. Same commands as below:

`sudo apt-get -qq install samba 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null && sudo systemctl enable smbd.service 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null`

- `apt-get..-qq` will suppress more installation dialogs
- `1> /dev/null` discards STDOUT
- `2> /dev/null` discards STDERR

Comment: Option `apt-get -yy` is not documented in manual. In which version it is implemented ?

Comment: @pasmanpasmański my mistake, It is `-qq`

Answer (score 4):

If your script uses `bash`, then you should use the `&>` operator for redirecting any output, that is both `stderr` and `stdout`:

```
sudo apt-get -y install samba &>/dev/null \
&& sudo systemctl enable smbd.service &> /dev/null
```